proof of differential structure on an n-dim projective space
Is it a mistake in Do Carmo's Riemannian geometry:
To prove there is a differentiable structure on $\mathbb{P}^n$, first it embeds $\mathbb{P}^n$ into n+1-dimensional Euclidean space, such that we can cover it by n+1 pieces of open sets $V_i=\{\left[x_1,...,x_{n+1}\right]:x_i\neq 0\}$, which is a collection of equivalence points. Then it gives an injective map $x_i:(x_1,...,x_n)\mapsto \left[x_1,...,x_{i-1},1,x_{i+1},...,x_n\right]$,from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $V_i$. However, then it just checks that $x_i^{-1}(V_j\cap V_i)$ is open, but in the definition, it should be that $x_i^{-1}(x_i(V_i)\cap x_j(V_j))$ is open, and in this case, is $x_i^{-1}(\left[x_1,...,x_{i-1},1,x_{i+1},...,x_{j-1},1,x_{j+1},...x_n\right])=(x_1,...,x_{i+1},...,x_{j-1},1,x_{j+1},...x_n)$, which is open. Is this correct?

$x_i(V_i)$ doesn't even make sense if your definition is $x_i:\Bbb{R}^n\to V_i\subset \Bbb{RP}^n$. Also, calling this map $x_i$ is just terrible notation.
